# Is there a way to subset data for Python statsmodels .get_margeff() like in R margins()?

Tags: python, subset, logistic-regression, statsmodels, marginal-effects

I created a model using mnlogit() from statsmodels that looks something similar to this:

> formula = "Switch_Variable ~ Prior_Complication_categ * C(Prior_Delivery_Type) +
> C(RaceName) + C(EthnicityName) + AgeInYears + C(Insurance) +
> TotalScore + Mortality_Score + Readmission_Score + num_deliveries"
> logmodel = smf.mnlogit(formula, data=analysis2_lagged).fit()

I know that you can use logmodel[.getmargeff()](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.get_margeff.html) to get marginal effects for the model. There is *atexog* parameter that allows you to get marginal effects for counterfactual dataset, where it changes the value of whatever variable you put into *atexog* for all observations and estimates the marginal effects based on that.

Instead, I wonder whether I could get marginal effects for a subset of data (such as dataset for Prior_Delivery_Type = 1). I know that R margins() allows you to subset data within the margins() function directly (details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#Subsetting)).

If there is no such feature in statsmodels, is there a workaround without using R? Any help would be appreciated!